# how to disable UI slider track Onclick event and disable when total is reach 100%?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-slider

I used 5 UI sliders in a single page for my project and it's working. But I have 2 problems.
You can see the live link: http://work.tretanz.com/uislider/

[image]

(1) when some one click on slider track the slider move to that point and my condition is not working, total value should not be grater then 100% and so,i want to disable onclick slider track event.

(2) when all slider total value reach 100% then all should be disable and it's work but the problem is that when i slide the current slider and total value reach the 100% then all slider disable but the current slider is sliding until i release the click. so,i want to fix that issue.

Help will be really appreciate.

Comment: The link provided is not working.

Comment: sorry for late reply.

Comment: check this link http://work.tretanz.com/uislider/ if page is not open then please refresh page 2 or 3 time link is working...